# Is the Nahkriin mask needed to get the last mask in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really want to get the last mask! I don't know if the Nahkriin mask is needed or not and I am getting really confused!

Do I need the Nahkriin mask in order to obtain the last mask? I'm playing on Xbox if it matters.

Answer (score 8):

The Nahkriin mask is indeed needed to get the Konahrik mask.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Mask states (emphasis mine):

> A bust is available for the following masks:
>
> - Volsung's Bust (see Volsung, Volsung Mask)
> - Vokun's Bust (see Vokun, Vokun Mask)
> - Otar's Bust (see Otar, Otar Mask)
> - Morokei's Bust (see Morokei, Morokei Mask)
> - Rahgot's Bust (see Rahgot,Rahgot Mask)
> - **Nahkriin's Bust** (see Nahkriin, Nahkriin Mask)
> - Hevnoraak's Bust (see Hevnoraak, Hevnoraak Mask)
> - Krosis' Bust (see Krosis, Krosis Mask)
>
> Once the eight masks are placed in each respective bust on the shrine,
>   the final mask Konahrik is revealed. The other masks may be taken from
>   the shrine once Konahrik is obtained.

This page clearly include Nahkriin's mask as a required mask.